# how to manage dependency of shared libraries using IVY

Tags: ivy

I have a EAR -

This EAR contains multiple WAR

Inside these WAR files there is a common JAR which is getting downloaded within each WAR file.
I want to remove this common JAR file into a shared Library. Also i want the latest version of JAR file everytime i rebuild my WAR, I am using Tomcat in Dev and Websphere min production.

We are using IVY for dependency management, Now. I have removed the common jar from the war file, but i dont know how to access the latest version of jar and download it in the shared library everytime i restart my server.

Can anyone help on this.?

Comment: Every time you restart your server? Or every time you build?

Answer (score 0):

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html

You'll need to add a dependency to your ivy.xml file, something along the lines of:

```
<dependency org="com.orgname" name="jarname" rev="latest.release"/>
```

Is this a JAR file you make yourself, or is it publicly available? If you make it yourself, you will have to publish it in a repository somewhere in your system.